# Using returned value (array of Strings) in another Swift file

Tags: arrays, swift

Apologize for a complete newbie question. This was the original array of Strings I wrote:

```
let fruit = ["apple1.jpg", "apple2.jpg", "apple3.jpg", ..... "apple10.jpg"]
```

First, I made a function in a separate Swift file (attached to the project) to replace above array, as the array's content might be changed based on several input factors later:

```
class Fruits {
    let fruit = "apple"

    func fruitName() -> [String] {
        let arrayA = (1...10).map({ "\(fruit)\($0).jpg" })
        return arrayA
        }
    }
}
```

This is everything written on Fruits.swift file. And then, back to original file, I wanted to replace the original `let fruit = ["", "", ...]` to something like let `fruit = Fruits.fruitName()` - by loading the returned arrayA. But it was a bit confusing to understand how to use returned String Array values in a different file, inside of a different Class bracket. I tried something like let `fruits = Fruits()`, `let fruit = fruits.fruitName()`, etc but it doesn't seem to successfully replace the original array code. I still need to create the constant `let fruit =` part. Is there any way to load the returned value in a separate file? Much appreciated. <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a property of a class to be directly accessible from anywhere in your code, you can make it static:

```
class Fruits {

    static let fruit = "apple"

    static func fruitName() -> [String] {
        let arrayA = (1...10).map({ "\(fruit)\($0).jpg" })
        return arrayA
    }
}

// usage:
let fruits = Fruits.fruitName()
```

Depending on your specific situation, you could even not have a class and have a global function that takes the fruit as a parameter:

```
func fruitNames(fruit: String) -> [String] {
    let arrayA = (1...10).map({ "\(fruit)\($0).jpg" })
    return arrayA
}

// usage:
let fruits = fruitNames(fruit: "apple")
```